# Loop amount of times given inside a For Loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a For Loop and it's asking the user how many times the loop should be looped inside the loop. How do I loop it the number of times given without repeating the question "how many names would you like to input"?

**The issue is that I don't want to repeat the question after the user answered it. When the user answers the question, I want it to ask for the names x amount of times and then move on.**

**The main problem is that I need to ask how many times to loop it after the name is asked. It's says it the assignment sheet.**

Thanks so much!

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
   System.out.println("Enter name #" + (i+1));
    names[i] = input.next();

    System.out.println("How many names would you like to input?");
    num = input.nextInt;
}
```

Comment: Move it outside the loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [for loop ( Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107425/for-loop-java)

Comment: Well then...still move it outside the loop as others have suggested but also ask for the first name entry outside the loop as well then start your **for** loop from index 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

You must move your `num` getter code outside of loop like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many names would you like to input?");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    String names[] = new String[num];

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter name #" + (i+1));
        names[i] = input.next();
    }

}
```

Comment: I need to ask how many times the user wants to input it after they enter the first name. It's in the assignment sheet and I don't know how to do that. Thanks though.

Comment: I've added the full working version and correct `num = input.next();`

Answer (score 0):

Always move these kinds of questions out of the loop rather than inside.

```
System.out.println("How many names would you like to input?");
   num = input.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

        System.out.println("Enter name #" + (i+1));
        names[i] = input.next();
    }
```

Comment: I need to ask how many times the user wants to input it after they enter the first name. It's in the assignment sheet and I don't know how to do that. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 num = input.next();
```

You are asking a numbers not a string should change the .next() to either nextInt or nextShort.

@DevilsHnd the first code won't work indeed, I never saw that String [] = new String [] use array before plus [this will explain better why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396182/difference-between-new-string-and-new-string-in-java).
@J.A.P  link with code may work

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Newpro{
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("how many times you want to loop?")
int num = sc.nextInt();//input the no of times you want to loop
String names[i] = new String[num];//initialize a string array for reading names
for(i=0;i<num;i++){
System.out.println("enter name#"+(i+1));
names[i]=sc.next();
}

for(j=0;j<num;j++){
//printing the names entered by you
System.out.println("the entered names by you are"+" "+names[j]);
}
```

as others suggested, you have to move your 'num' getter part out of the loop and after that initialize a string array for reading your names by specifying how many names you want to enter(index of string array = number of names you want to enter and no of times you want to loop as well==>'num') and based on that number the looping will be done with above code.

finally iterate through the array and print the names entered by you.

Edit:1

check with the below code if you need to ask "how many names user wants to input AFTER it asks for a first name.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Newpro2{
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
//make sure you create a string array with index = no of names you want to 
//enter
String[] names = new String[10];
System.out.println("enter name#1");
names[0]= sc.next();
System.out.println("how many inputs you want to give?");
num=sc.nextInt();//give the no of inputs you want to give here
//read the remaining names
for(int i=1;i<num;i++){
System.out.println("enter name#"+(i+1));
names[i] = sc.next();
}

//print all the names entered by you
for(int j=0;j<num;j++){
System.out.println("entered name#"+(j+1)+"by you is"+" "+names[j]);
}
```

Comment: I would've done the exact same thing in the first place, however, the main problem here is that I need to ask how many names the user wants to input AFTER it asks for a first name. I can't change the order because it says I need to do this in the assignment sheet. Thanks though!